# How does JPA's @OneToMany know the Generic entity type at runtime

Tags: java, generics, jpa

According to the JavaDoc on @OneToMany, you don't need to specify *targetEntity* if the "collection property is defined using Java generics". On top of this, you don't need to instantiate the collection property at construction time, but can leave it as null. For example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
private Collection<Qualification> qualification;
```

However, as I understood Generics and Type Erasure, at runtime all it's possible to see is that this is a Collection and not a Collection of Qualification - because as I understood it the generic type has been erased here already.

How does this work? What am I missing?

Comment: Actually at runtime, you *can* get the generic type for method parameters & return types via `Method.getGenericParameterTypes()` and `getGenericReturnType()` -- but not from arbitrary variables or object references. Spring uses this technique for data-binding, for example.

Comment: But this is a variable, and - as I understand it - you can use field level binding and not need a getter or setter to be available for this field, so there wouldn't be a method that can be inspected for this metadata. However, I didn't know you could do that with Methods, so that's useful to know too :)

Comment: Aha - Got it I think. You can also do a *getGenericType()* on a java.lang.reflect.Field object, which will give you the generic type information for a class field, which then means we know what we're looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas W for pointing this out. You can get the Generic type information from Methods and Fields on a class using reflection, using *Method.getGenericReturnType()* and *Field.getGenericType()*, which will then give enough information to know what's needed to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You missing the conter-part of this annotation:

With `mappedBy="student"` you defined the possible Classes, because you are "linking" to another database table. And that table has a Java-Binding, too. So JPA will try to create an Object from the N-table and add them into the list.

**update**

In JPA, there is something called `@DiscriminatorColumn`, if you setup a table for all inherited classes. You also can specify one table per conreete class.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: So how does it work if you have multiple entities mapped to the same table? Such as if you are using Single Table Inheritance, or just having entities that are simpler to make the code easier or more performant. Or does it not work and that's just a generally bad idea in this case?

Comment: Actually, playing with it more, mappedBy on the @OneToMany annotation defines the column name to map with *on the target entity*, which still doesn't explain how it knows what the target entity is in the first place...